# Is it correct to say that "Java is platform independent but version dependent ?"

Tags: java

Our project application uses Java 5 and now when I update Java 6, there are some kind of inconsistency with functionality and seeing this effects our manager passed comment that **"Java is platform independent but version dependent"**, Is it really true ?

Comment: What inconsistencies did you see?

Comment: We have legacy code and than we have different version of it, latest version of it was using Java 5 but when Java 6 came we all developers had updated our system with Java 6 but then we try to build the code which was initially in Java 5, that code was not building and we all had to go revert back to Java 5 and this was an major issue with our application and it really pissed off our Manager and so he passed this statement in meeting where we had sr. architects, sr manager, IT directors and other executives.

Comment: I wonder *why* your Java 5 codebase wouldn't *build* with Java 6.  Are you using some funky Ant tasks or something?

Comment: I *really* would like to know what specific code broke your build.  I have handled several complex applications and frameworks from Java 1.1 through Java 5 and have never had a problem with a new version of Java, either in compile or run.

Comment: Most things that break with a new Java version are things where the programmer coded to a side-effect or result instead of to the documented specification of an API.

Comment: One example where Java5 source does not compile with Java6 is if you implement JDBC Connection. They have added lots of extra methods to the interface in Java6, and that makes it source-incompatible.

Comment: @Thilo - why would adding extra methods in Java 6 stop Java 5 code from compiling?  I suppose it might do if they added new methods to an `interface` and your code included a `class` that implemented the `interface`.  But would you implement your own JDBC connection class?

Comment: From my point of view, Java is NOT platform-independent, Java IS THE PLATFORM you are programming to :D.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, exactly, they added new methods to the interface (Connection), and that prevents existing code from compiling (until you add corresponding implementations). And, yes, some people do implement JDBC classes.

Comment: FYI - this 'adding classes to interfaces breaks backwards code compatability' thing is the reason that many core 'interfaces' are now developed as abstract base classes instead of interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New versions of Java will run code compiled in previous versions. So if you compile your code in Java 5 and then try to run it in a Java 6 environment it will run.

If you compile in Java 6 though it will not run in a Java 5 environment.

Comment: This isn't necessary true.  There are pieces of code in 1.5 that won't compile in 1.6.  I'm not sure if this is an Eclipse-compiler issue, however with 1.5, it allowed you to place @Override annotations on interface implementations.  In fact, Eclipse would add these by default.  In 1.6, this is a compiler error since it doesn't make sense logically.  But realistically, this is nit-picking.

For the most part, this is right. :P

Comment: He's not talking about compiling 5 code with a 6 compiler.  He's talking about running already-compiled 5 code in a 6 runtime.

Comment: This is not absolutely true. Even if they are minor, there are binary-incompatibilities between versions. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html#incompatibilities for upwards incompatibilities between Java 5 and Java 6.

Comment: @Tom.  Read the OP's first comment.  She talks about the **build** failing.

Comment: @Malaxeur: The issue with @Override is the other way around: Java 6 code won't compile under Java 5 because the Java 5 compiler complains about the @Override annotations.  It is not a compiler issue per-se.  Sun's Java compiler / language folks quietly "corrected" the semantics of @Override.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java SE Compatibility at a Glance](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/compatibility.jsp):

> The Java Platform, Standard
>   Edition(Java SE) is strongly
>   compatible with previous versions of
>   the Java platform. Each version of
>   Java SE has upwards
>   binary-compatibility with the previous
>   version, except for the
>   incompatibilities noted in the
>   documentation. Java SE does not
>   support downward source compatibility,
>   however: If source files use new
>   language features or Java SE platform
>   APIs, they will not be usable with an
>   earlier version of the Java platform.
>
> The documentation describes any
>   compatibility issues between the
>   current version and the version
>   immediately preceding it.
>
> - [Incompatibilities between Java SE 6 and J2SE 5.0](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html)
> - [Incompatibilities in J2SE 5.0 (since 1.4.2)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html)
> - [Incompatibilities in J2SE 1.4.2](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/compatibility.html)
> - [Incompatibilities in J2SE 1.4.1](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.1/compatibility.html)

So, as written, each version of Java SE has upwards binary-compatibility with the previous version, except for the listed incompatibilities (which are considered as minor). That said, no one forces you to upgrade (as long as support is not an issue). If you don't want to benefit from the new features of a new version (like performance improvements, API improvements, etc), don't do it. But in my opinion, the benefits are in general worth the (minor) efforts. Check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you upgrade any framework there may be some unforeseen changes, which is why unit tests are important, as you can then run your tests and ensure that the behavior hasn't changed.

There is nothing that states JDK6 will function as JDK5 did at all times. For example, it appears that the ordering in a HashMap will differ between the two versions, but, since a HashMap is unordered, that isn't a real problem, unless you expect the order to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, new versions of Java introduce new Java features. However, maintaining backwards compatibility for all time is notoriously hard, and code written for newer versions of Java can not be expected to work with older versions of the run-time environment.